# How to get Drag & Drop in ASP.NET TreeView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

Is there a way to enable Drag & Drop in ASP.NET TreeView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no "easy/good" way to do this because the control was not created with that feature in mind but there are a lot of alternatives to the ASP.NET TreeView. We use Telerik and before that, we were using ComponentArt.

As a side note, I don't recommend the controls from ASP.NET WebForms... the only one I use is the repeater... but this is another story. And if you are new to ASP.NET, have a look to ASP.NET MVC which I think is a lot better then ASP.NET WebForms.

Finally, [think before using Treeviews...](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000246.html)